# $SU(2)$ doublets from the transformation law of a matrix of scalar fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, group-theory, klein-gordon-equation

If we have a $2 \times 2$ $SU(2)_L$ and $SU(2)_R$ matrix $\Phi=\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d 
\end{bmatrix}$, where a, b, c and d are four complex Klein-Gordon fields, that under a gauge group $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ transforms as $\Phi \rightarrow U_L \Phi U_R^\dagger$, where $U_L$ and $U_R$ are the SU(2) matrices representing the transformations of $SU(2)_L$ and $SU(2)_R$, how can we find the doublets of $SU(2)_L$ and $SU(2)_R$ formed by the fields $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ and their complex conjugates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Each *column* of Φ is an $SU_L(2)$ doublet, since $U_L$ only scrambles rows.
- Each *row* of Φ is an $SU_R(2)$ doublet, since $U_R$ only scrambles columns.  N.B. In response to your comment, $\Phi \sigma_x =\begin{bmatrix}
  c & a \\
  d & b 
  \end{bmatrix}$. So the first column has been interchanged with the second one, rigidly; in that sense it has been altered.

Extra credit. Which bilinears of Φ and $\Phi^\dagger$ are $SU_L(2)$-invariant, and which $SU_R(2)$-invariant?

Comment: Are the columns of $\Phi$ $SU(2)_R$-invariants and the rows of $\Phi$ $SU(2)_L$-invariants?

Comment: NO!  Why should they be? $SU_R(2)$ scrambles them (untouched) with each other. There is no substitute for practice. Observe what $\sigma_{x~~L}$ does; what $\sigma_{x~~R}$ does; and compute $[\sigma_{x~~L},  \sigma_{z~~R}]$.

Comment: $\Phi \Phi^\dagger$ is $SU(2)_R$ invariant and $\Phi^\dagger \Phi$ is $SU(2)_L$ invariant, is that right?

Comment: Correct! You are there....

Comment: That happens because the generators of $SU(2)$ are unitary, right?

Comment: No, the generators are hermitian, but their exponentials with an *i* in front of the generators are thus unitary elements.

Comment: If we have another $SU(2)$ generated by the sum of the generators of $SU(2)_R$ with the generators of $SU(2)_L$, how would the elements of this new $SU(2)$ act on $\Phi$?

Comment: As you might expect, if you exponentiated the sum into a Cartesian product, $U\Phi U^\dagger$, using the *same U* for L and R!  This is called the Vector subgroup of the Cartesian product group.